# android textview drawable auto mirror not working for RTL support

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-layout-direction

I have given `RTL` support to my application for the Arabic language.
everything works fine except one case.

if I used `android:drawableRight` or `android:drawableEnd` in my `TexView` as below. 
and icon positions are showing perfect if I enable or disable `RTL` mode. but auto mirror not working for a drawable.

```
<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/str_next"
          android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_next"
/>
```

Comment: Have you tried android:autoMirrored="true" . OR using <integer name="locale_mirror_flip">0</integer>
Using this in this in your value folder .

Comment: @MiniChip Yes. I tried it. it is working for imageView, not for textView.

Comment: https://android.jlelse.eu/rtl-support-on-android-here-is-all-you-need-know-e13f2df512e2